# Как настроить D-Link DIR-655?

Tags: wifi, роутер

Добрый день!

Настроил локальную сеть через wifi роутер DIR-655, на клиентских машинах в качестве сетевух стоят D-Link Wireless N 150 USB.

Клиенты через DIR-655 ходят в инет со скоростью провайдера 8мб/с.

А вот в локальной сети скорость больше 1мб/с не поднимается.

Скачивал последнюю прошивку на роутер. Пробовал отключать QoS в роутере и на клиентах, результат тот же. Какие еще будут советы?

Comment: в advanced есть раздел wish попробуй его отключить может поможет

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отключай брендмауэры и всё что может проверять трафик. ещё попробуй [прошивку](ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Router/DIR-655/Firmware/) поменять.